# How to display Chinese characters in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, jupyter

I have an excel file that contains Chinese characters. I imported it to jupyter notebook using Pandas. The code I used is shown below:

```
data = pd.read_excel('foodjournal.xlsx')
words = data['name'].values.tolist()
```

I have Chinese characters such as this:

êùçè•≠

What type of encoding is this? How can I display this as a Chinese character?

Comment: Clearly the `utf-8` encoding is wrong here, but without seeing the actual bytes, we really have no way to tell. Please [edit] your question to show the `repr()` of a sample; see also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: yeah, a sample is needed. you can try using `utf-16` or `latin-1` or `ascii`. `utf-8` supports chinese characters, so if there is no problem in encoding, it should support.

Comment: Note we most likely don't see the same characters you see in your post. On my laptop, I see text similar to:

"I have Chinese characters such as this:

euce.="